# Get 404 page while load flask app

Tags: python, flask

I've just read about flask.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/

First tried to write a small app, worked good. Then I split app to the files and got 404 empty page. Could anyone give me an advice.
Where I was wrong.

structure of project:

```
project/
    application/
        templates/
            main.html
        __init__.py
        views.py
    run.py
```

---

file `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

---

file `run.py`

```
import os
import sys
from application import app

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

file `views.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from application import app

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("main.html")
```

Comment: you need to use blueprints ... your never importing views anywhere that I can see

Comment: Is it mandatory to use blueprints? In quickstart docs page I saw  anything about them.

Comment: no of coarse its not mandatory(but it will probably greatly simplify your life) ... but if your not importing your views anywhere how do you expect it to do anything at all?

Comment: It'll need to know how to route or pick up views. What happens if you add line `import application.views` in your `__init__.py`?

Comment: @xbb It's worked. Thanks a lot. But I can't understand where does a views call? I only added this code `import application.views` to the end of file

Comment: When you initialize the app, it will call __init__.py, where it's going to call or import views and knows how to dispatch/route requests

Answer (score 1):

In `run.py`, you're importing `from application import app` which brings in your `app` object from `__init__.py`. Great!

But that's all it does.

Your `views.py` file gets the same variable from `__init__.py` and registers a view. *This* is what you want to import from `run.py`:

```
import os
import sys
from application.views import app

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When you impor `app` from `views`, `views.py` pulls `app` from `application`. Thus, your `run.py` gets the `app` object, but it comes from `views.py` where it had the route registered.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and this helped - thanks!